# How to ensure cross browser AAC+ playback?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have an Icecast server serving AAC+ (HE v2). I use JPlayer in my webpage to play the content. In Chromium without Flash Player it works just fine.

For Flash enabled browsers it does not work out of the box. I read that Icecast wants to have a "type=.flv" appended to the stream request to make the content playble by Flash Player, and although I have trouble finding the Icecast documentation about it, indeed it works on Firefox with Flash Player 11. But it does not play on other browsers with Flash 15 and above, namely Google Chrome on Linux, Firefox and Internet Explorer on Windows. Google Chrome plays it just fine by disabling Flash Player.

The audio data are downloaded correctly as shown by Developer Tools, audio is heard for about one second and then silence.

Is there anything I can try to make AAC+ playback possible with Flash Player ?

A link:

`http://148.251.184.14:18044/chr_xmas`

By default it returns a header with Content Type audio/aac. By appending "?type=.flv" (with a dot), it returns Content Type video/x-flv.

Comment: Do you have a link we can test? Show how the links look like for **.aac** and also show how it looks if you do the **type=flv**. First thing I could check is that its working as intended. Also Flash does not play AAC audio files alone (they must be inside some AV container format like FLV or MP4).

Comment: Link: http://148.251.184.14:18044/chr_xmas

Comment: Hi, I tested your links and they work fine via Flash programming tools  (IDE) for both AAC and FLV. Now I assumed from the Flash tag that you were a coder who could handle ActionScript but it just hit me that really you want help for setting up JPlayer. No need to learn a new language just for one stream but you can try **[Muses Radio Player](https://www.muses.org/)**.. The page to **[setup a test is here](https://www.muses.org/setup)** can be slightly slow to load the test stream but it will work (tested).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, I will give Muses a try. I suspect there is something wrong with flash player or jPlayer's .swf because it plays just fine in Linux and not on Windows. Additionally I can see in the network tab that the stream is downloading but no sound is heard. Also, the strangest thing happened. I had forgotten IE in the background and after about an hour, it started playing the AAC stream by itself. Do you have any recommendations for debugging Flash Player ? I checked Flash Player's flashlog.txt and policyfiles.txt but got no useful hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a [jPlayer issue](https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer/issues/197). I noticed at the bottom a [mention](https://github.com/SBSRadio/jPlayer/commit/6bce06d0d37fea25f2fa6aaae256767add849e82) by a jPlayer fork with a crude hack which is good enough for my purposes.

It didn't work right off the bat though, I changed the line to

```
if( myStream.bytesLoaded > 2048 ) return 1;
```

as it seems that in my case bytesTotal was not uint.MAX_VALUE. I had to compile a new .swf with flex and it worked like a charm on Firefox and Internet Explorer.